# Graph is not being returned by Plotly Dash Callback

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm doing some GIS analysis and got a bit flustered.

I need to create a interactive plotly dash app, where you have two multi dropdown dash core components that update values on a px.scatter_mapbox map. The DataFrame has the following "Filters"/Fields I need in the dropdowns: Race/Ethnicity and City. I'm stuck at this point:

1. Click on the Race Drop down (Multi) (works)
2. City Options are appropriately filled (works)
3. Map won't update-- just returns what you see below.

Here is my code:

```
import dash.dependencies
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
px.set_mapbox_access_token(mapbox_access_token)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

re_indicators = df["RE"].unique()

city_indicators = df["CITY"].unique()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Race & Ethnicity'),
        dcc.Dropdown( id = "re",
                     options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in re_indicators],
                     value = ["White"], 
                     multi = True
                     ), 
        html.Label('City'),
        dcc.Dropdown( id = "city",
                     options=[], 
                     value = [],
                     multi = True
                     ),        
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='my_map',
            figure = {})
    ])
    ])])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('city', 'options'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('re', 'value')
)
def re_picker(choose_re):
  
  if len(choose_re) > 0: 
    
    dff = df[df.RE.isin(choose_re)]

  return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in (dff.CITY.unique())]

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('city', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('city', 'options')
)
def set_city_value(available_options): 
  return [x['value'] for x in available_options]

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('my_map', 'figure'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('re', 'value'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('city', 'value')]
)
def update_figure(selected_re, selected_city): 
  if len(selected_re) == 0:
    return print("nope")
  else:
    df_filtered = dff[(dff['CITY'] == selected_city)]
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df_filtered,
                            lat="Latitude",
                            lon="Longitude",
                            zoom=1)
    return fig

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(host = "127.0.0.1", port = "8888", mode= "inline", debug = False)
```

[Ouput Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTnXZ.png)

Comment: As you didn't share the data I can't fully reproduce the problem, but I guess that the error is coming from this line: `dff['CITY'] == selected_city`. Try replacing it with `dff['CITY'] .isin(selected_city)`. Note that `selected_city` is a list, as it is the value of a multi-dropdown.

Comment: really need some sample data,  I can find demographics by country on kaggle but not by city

Answer (score 1):

- you have not provided any data, have generated some sample data
- there are a number issues with your code. All actually generate obvious exceptions

  1. scoping, *dff* is note scoped across all **callbacks** however you are assuming it is.  Fixes are to only have *df* as global scope
  2. `list` equality makes no sense.  use `isin()`
  3. better practice is to use `raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate` if conditions for **callback** are not met

#### solution

```
import dash.dependencies
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# px.set_mapbox_access_token(mapbox_access_token)

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]
app = JupyterDash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

re_indicators = df["RE"].unique()
city_indicators = df["CITY"].unique()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Label("Race & Ethnicity"),
                dcc.Dropdown(
                    id="re",
                    options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in re_indicators],
                    value=["White"],
                    multi=True,
                ),
                html.Label("City"),
                dcc.Dropdown(id="city", options=[], value=[], multi=True),
                html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="my_map", figure={})]),
            ]
        )
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("city", "options"), dash.dependencies.Input("re", "value")
)
def re_picker(choose_re):
    if len(choose_re) > 0:
        dff = df[df.RE.isin(choose_re)]
    else:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    return [{"label": i, "value": i} for i in (dff.CITY.unique())]


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("city", "value"),
    dash.dependencies.Input("city", "options"),
)
def set_city_value(available_options):
    return [x["value"] for x in available_options]


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("my_map", "figure"),
    [dash.dependencies.Input("re", "value"), dash.dependencies.Input("city", "value")],
)
def update_figure(selected_re, selected_city):
    if not selected_re or not selected_city or len(selected_re)==0 or len(selected_city)==0:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate

    # df_filtered = dff[(dff['CITY'] == selected_city)] # this is out of scope!!!
    df_filtered = df.loc[df["CITY"].isin(selected_city) & df["RE"].isin(selected_re)]
    fig = px.scatter_mapbox(df_filtered, lat="Latitude", lon="Longitude", zoom=1).update_layout(mapbox={"style":"carto-positron"})
    return fig


# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(host="127.0.0.1", port="8888", mode="inline", debug=False)
```

[image]

#### data

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""RE,Longitude,Latitude,CITY
Black,-120.99774156574261,37.559165406261,Stanislaus
Pacific,-120.65111562736087,38.446389516422855,Amador
Pacific,-119.81550247702623,36.07536100517565,Kings
Black,-121.95120685287338,37.92342159137978,Contra Costa
Native,-118.26100262413676,34.197992401614535,Los Angeles
Asian,-120.7249673888429,41.58984787469562,Modoc
White,-121.95120685287338,37.92342159137978,Contra Costa
Hispanic,-123.9578138104391,41.74495737627584,Del Norte
Black,-122.39220680431815,39.59840477506362,Glenn
Pacific,-122.04052155027398,40.7637665910163,Shasta
Black,-120.71766862423333,37.19185694553567,Merced
Native,-121.69484223375345,39.03452277403378,Sutter
Black,-115.9938588669452,33.743676039870444,Riverside
Black,-119.90551726806129,37.58152187924647,Mariposa
Pacific,-117.41078970333236,36.51112681410214,Inyo
Black,-119.76264585146096,37.218035870388235,Madera
Pacific,-123.43155392039253,39.433623844726505,Mendocino
Black,-121.34428014540734,38.4493728777556,Sacramento
White,-120.7249673888429,41.58984787469562,Modoc
Pacific,-119.64932124370894,36.758179506828185,Fresno
White,-119.81550247702623,36.07536100517565,Kings
Native,-121.91788591709779,37.65054956250571,Alameda
Asian,-121.07499558470187,36.6057059207284,San Benito
Native,-120.52464692805631,38.778737966889466,El Dorado
Pacific,-120.55413218695809,38.204606401638536,Calaveras
Hispanic,-116.17845588321354,34.84143467938159,San Bernardino
Black,-122.23388486629841,40.12573617303074,Tehama
White,-121.90162044594241,38.68664649354098,Yolo
Native,-120.45219691432906,35.38741552944272,San Luis Obispo
Pacific,-119.82065303166894,38.59725063024503,Alpine"""))
```

Comment: This is wonderful, Rob. Thank you so much for your thorough input!